# What does an interaction with a confounder mean within a multivariate regression analysis?

Tags: interaction, multivariate-regression, confounding

In a multivariate regression analysis, I examine the effect that a treatment method has on subjects' hemoglobin levels. Since this is a retrospective study, I could not control for gender (or age) by randomization prior to collection. As a result, I control for gender in my analyses. The treatment effect remains significant even when I control for gender. However, when I include an interaction term between gender and treatment, the treatment effect is no longer significant. However, the interaction term is significant. Unfortunately, I don't know what to conclude from this. Whether I should report the interaction and what exactly it means in that case. Hopefully, someone could help me with this, thank you!

Geschlecht means Gender, Gruppen_Zwei is the treatment and HB_postop is the hemoglobin level

[image: This picture shows the interaction between treatment and gender. In condition one female (w) have a higher hemoglobin level, in condition two it is the other way around]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you include an interaction term in a model it also changes the interpretation of the two "main effect" terms in the model - they no longer estimate the "average" effect of the original variables, but the effect of each when the other is zero.

In your case you have an interaction between two binary variables: treatment (1=got treatment and 0=didn't get treatment) and gender (1=female 0=male). You include those two variables along with an interaction (treatment * gender) in a model of Y. The interpretation is as follows:

The coefficient for "treatment" estimates the effect of being in the treatment group (as opposed to the control for MALES (gender=0)

The coefficient for "gender" estimates the effect of being female (as opposed to male) for those in the CONTROL group (treatment=0)

The coefficient for the interaction term estimates the difference between the treatment effect for females (as opposed to for males). In other words, to get the effect of the treatment for females you have to add the interaction term coefficient to the main treatment coefficient.

So let's say that the treatment coefficient is nonsignificant, the gender coefficient is positive and significant and the interaction term is positive and significant. This means that:

a)For MALES getting the treatment is not associated with a significant difference in outcomes
b) for those in the control group being female is associated with higher outcomes
c) For FEMALES getting the treatment is associated with a significantly MORE POSITIVE difference in outcomes, compared to for males.

In other words, the interaction tells you that the effect of the treatment is significantly bigger for females than for males. What it doesn't tell you is if the effect for females is significantly different from ZERO. To test that you could just  male "female" the reference category for gender instead of male.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe you could answer me that as well, if the gender effect is also not significant, does this mean that there is not difference for both gender in the control group? And what if in the control group are almost no male (just two of 27), is it then even reasonable to include an interaction term?

Comment: Actually, I just did what you said and releveled the baseline group, than I get an significant effect for treatment, but not for gender and a significant interaction. So the effect for females is significantly different from zero. So now I know that treatment makes a significant difference for female but not for male (and this also explains my interaction). But is it a problem that I have only so few male in the first condition (actually in the second as well as there are only 9 male and 19 female patients)?

Comment: Failing to find a significant effect doesn't mean one doesn't exist; it just means you don't have the precision to detect it, and having a tiny sample of men will mean you don't have the precision to find men-specific effects. 

To interpret the coefficient on treatment as the average effect collapsing across gender, subtract the mean of gender prior to including it and its interaction with treatment in the model.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Noah! Could you explain me a little further what you mean with "subtract the mean of gender prior to including it and its interaction with treatment in the model"? that would be great!

Comment: If gender is coded as 0/1 (i.e., rather than M/W), running `lm(HB_postop ~ Gruppen_Zwei * I(gender-mean(gender)), data = data)` will allow you to interpret the coefficient on Gruppen_Zwei as the average effect of treatment (i.e., rather than the effect of treatment at gender = 0). This will not change the significance of the interaction term or the fit of the model.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, that is very helpful! Maybe I can ask you one last thing. How would you go about reporting the interaction, since there are only two men in the first condition, and the interaction of gender and treatment is probably more of an artifact than really having meaning. Actually, I only included gender to control for the unequal gender distribution, i.e., to see if the treatment effect could possibly be explained by it. But since this is not the case and the treatment effect still exists, I don't know what sense it makes to report the interaction.